# In C++ is it possible to return an element of the class from a class member function?

Tags: c++, function, class, member

In C++ is it possible to return an element of the class from a class member function?

```
namespace translation2d
{
    class translation2d
    {
        public:
           double x;
          double y;

        public:
            translation2d()
            {
                x=0;
                y=0;
            }

        public:
            translation2d translateBy(translation2d other); 
            //being interpreted as a constructor?
    }

    translation2d translation2d::translateBy(translation2d other)
    {//I need this member function to return an object of type translation2d
        x+=other.x;
        y+=other.y;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried:

    return translation2d();
    
?

Comment: By calling `translateBy(...)` you modify your `translation2d` object. Do you need to return a copy of the current `translation2d` object, or a new `translation2d` object?

Comment: "Yes", a class member can create an object of the same type as the class it is defined in. (Not sure what else that leaves in the question.. hence the vote-for-focus-required.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

6502's answer is correct, and the code is neat.

I just wanted to give a fix that minimises changes to your original code, for clarity:

```
translation2d translation2d::translateBy(translation2d other)
{
    translation2d copy = *this;

    copy.x += other.x;
    copy.y += other.y;

    return copy;
}
```

The idea is to:

1. Create a copy of the "current" object so you don't impact the original (you don't want that)
2. Return that copy once you've adjusted it with data from `other`

Written another way, we can avoid copying the argument *again* since you already passed it by value:

```
translation2d translation2d::translateBy(translation2d copy)
{
    copy.x += this->x;
    copy.y += this->y;

    return copy;
}
```

… though I'd expect the compiler to do this for you in reality, and I find this version of the code harder to read. See the last section of this answer for other ways to avoid the extra copy (assuming that you are inclined to worry about it).

---

An alternative version of this function would actually translate the *current* object rather than returning a new one:

```
translation2d& translation2d::translateBy(translation2d other)
{
    this->x += other.x;
    this->y += other.y;

    return *this;
}
```

Notice that I still return something, rather than `void`; in this case I've followed the convention of returning a reference to the current object, which aids in chaining multiple modifications to the same object. You'll find this pattern a lot in operator overloading.

Technically the `this->` is unnecessary, but it makes the function a bit easier to understand.

---

Note that 6502 changed the function to take `other` by const-reference, which is often a good idea and you should consider doing that too (though copying two `double`s is so cheap that it may not be worth the indirection).

Comment: You have unneeded extra copies. If you pass in a copy, you may as well use it for the "copy" you need to make. Instead of making another new version, with the values of "this"  ... use "other" as the copy instead. You're right, 2 doubles is hardly anything, but if you do that millions of times, it adds up.

Comment: @ChrisMM: Actually I'd expect a compiler to elide that kind of thing when there are no changes to observable side effects and it all takes place in one function. I wouldn't expect to see any performance hit here no matter how many times you do it. But you're right that other approach would be neater. I deliberately avoided changing anything relating to the function argument (as explored in the final paragraph) but perhaps ignored it a bit _too_ much.

Comment: @ChrisMM I've edited the answer to discuss this a bit. Don't think it really warranted a downvote, though?

Comment: Yay, the edit brought the page to the attention of more people who thought this answer should be downvoted and the code-dump explanation-less alternative should get more votes. Love this site.

Comment: Not my downvote. Would have to look at the assembly to see if it would generate the second copy or not. The return wouldn't cause a copy, but I think the call to the function would, and the "copy" variable too. Now I'm curious, but just on phone so cant check.

Comment: @ChrisMM [Here's a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/tKdBKh) showing that the assembly in both cases is identical (& [screenshot for posterity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qjrX.png)). This isn't surprising; the programs literally do the same thing. "Optimising compilers" build programs that do as your source code describes; they don't just convert each line of your C++ verbatim into some assembly instructions.

Comment: (by "do the same thing" I of course mean in terms of observable outputs for a given set of inputs)

Answer (score 5):

Sure, with something like

```
struct Translation2d {
    double x, y;
    Translation2d(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    Translation2d translate_by(const Translation2d& other) {
        return Translation2d(x + other.x, y + other.y);
    }
};
```